# Argument passed to verify() is of type Scanner and is not a mock

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to test that a Scanner object has been closed after being used in a try-with-resources. However I'm getting an error that says that my mocked Scanner  is not a mock. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is the method that I'm trying to test:

```
 private Collection<String> getCellIPs(String resultStoreHost, String path) throws IOException, PermissionsException {
        Path tempDir = null;
        Path cellFile = null;
        List<String> results = new LinkedList<>();

        try {
            // Download the file.
            SecureFTPClient ftpClient = new SecureFTPClient(resultStoreHost, "user", "password", true);
            tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory(Paths.get("/store"), "celllist");
            ftpClient.downloadFile(path + "/" + ResultStore.PARTITIONS_FILENAME, tempDir.toString());

            cellFile = tempDir.resolve(ResultStore.PARTITIONS_FILENAME);

            try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(cellFile)) {
                scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

                while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String ip = scanner.next();
                    results.add(ip);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                // Cleanup temporary files
                if(cellFile != null) {
                    Files.delete(cellFile);
                }
                if (tempDir != null) {
                    Files.delete(tempDir);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.warn("Couldn't delete temporary files in " + tempDir);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({DTDeliverQueryResultsJob.class, SecureFTPClient.class, Scanner.class})
public class DTDeliverQueryResultsJobTest
{
    WorkflowRuntime mockWorkflowRuntime;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockWorkflowRuntime = PowerMockito.mock(WorkflowRuntime.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(WorkflowRuntime.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockWorkflowRuntime);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCellIPsWithNoException() throws Exception {
        // Required mocks for DTDeliverQueryResultsJob
        SecureFTPClient mockSecureFTPClient = PowerMockito.mock(SecureFTPClient.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SecureFTPClient.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockSecureFTPClient);

        Scanner mockScanner = PowerMockito.mock(Scanner.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockScanner.hasNext()).thenReturn(false);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Scanner.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockScanner);

        DTDeliverQueryResultsJob dtDeliverQueryResultsJob = PowerMockito.spy(new DTDeliverQueryResultsJob(mockWorkflowRuntime));

        // Using Whitebox to call private method
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(dtDeliverQueryResultsJob, "getCellIPs", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());

        // Verify that Scanner has been closed by try-with-resources
        Mockito.verify(mockScanner).close();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (dictionary.ZBaseLogsService).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.



org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type Scanner and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();

    at com.zantaz.applications.retention.workflow.steps.DTDeliverQueryResultsJobTest.testGetCellIPsWithNoException(DTDeliverQueryResultsJobTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:66)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of your NPE.

Comment: What is the name of the class that contains the method getCellIPs() ?

Comment: The class that contains getCellIPs is DTDeliverQueryResultsJob